# How to use XML.modify 'replace value' with a WHERE clause

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, dml, xml-dml

I have an XML column that contains foreign key ID values stored within XML.  I need to be able to update the XML when the ID value changes (e.g. change all instances of "26" to "999").

From my readings [here](http://www.olcot.co.uk/sql-blogs/introduction-to-xml-dml-part-2---using-the-modify-method-replace-value-of) I've tried to adapt the code, but it isn't actually updating:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (xmlCol xml);

INSERT INTO @tmp (xmlCol) SELECT 
('<search><groups><g id="25" /><g id="26" /></groups></search>') UNION ALL SELECT
('<search><groups><g id="2" /><g id="9" /></groups></search>') UNION ALL SELECT
('<search><groups><g id="7" /><g id="12" /><g id="26" /></groups></search>');

SELECT * FROM @tmp;

DECLARE @oldId int = 26;
DECLARE @newId int = 999;

UPDATE @tmp SET xmlCol.modify('replace value of 
    (/search/groups/g/text()[.=(sql:variable("@oldId"))])[1]
with 
    (sql:variable("@newId"))');

SELECT * FROM @tmp;
```

What is the correct `modify` logic to achieve this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XPath you specified matches value to text of the element `g` and would worked for elements like `<g>26</g>`, in your case you have to change XPath to match `id` attribute of the element. Assuming groups are unique within `/search/groups` you may try follwoing:

```
UPDATE @tmp
SET xmlCol.modify('replace value of 
    (/search/groups/g[@id=sql:variable("@oldId")]/@id)[1]
with 
    (sql:variable("@newId"))');
```